# Facebook Enhanced Auth Dialog Not Always Showing Up

Tags: facebook

I've carefully followed the instructions here to enable the new Facebook authentication dialog for my app:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/

Here is an example app page:

https://apps.facebook.com/pulsetrack/watch/EP007055290160

Every time I head to my app (before accepting) it properly re-directs me to the authentication page as expected:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=303944262956409&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fpulsetrack%2Fwatch%2FEP007055290160&response_type=token&canvas=1&perms=email%2Cuser_likes%2Cpublish_actions

This works great for me and I always see the aggregation preview, but some people are reporting that they see a simple authentication screen that just asks for e-mail address and says it won't be posting to their timeline.

My questions:

- Is the URL possibly just getting screwed up (encoded funny or something stripping out all of the permissions?)
- Are some people not yet able to see the enhanced auth dialog?
- Does this work for you?
- Something else?

Here are the dialogs people are seeing:

**The Good Dialog** 
[image: Good dialog:]

**The Bad Dialog**
[image: The bad dialog]

Comment: I get a same issue with the facebook js sdk by doing : FB.ui({method: 'permissions.request',perms: 'publish_actions', display: 'popup'}); I get a simple authentification window, only the title : 'Permission request' is good. I think it's a facebook big issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Let's see if we can find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that only admins/developers/testers of your application (as listed in the Facebook developer app) can be authenticated for publish_actions until we open up Timeline to everyone. So non-developers of your app get the auth dialog with no timeline preview (and no publish_actions), and your app developers get the new one with publish_actions.

Comment: So if we go live now it will be easy to ask for that permission later I assume? Something like this? http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3388367/check-for-extended-permissions-with-new-facebook-javascript-sdk

Comment: @Jeff IIRC, wasn't it planned on 1st October to allow timeline to everyone?

Comment: @genesis, No date has been announced.

Comment: @JeffSherlock: When I was publishing my own Timeline, ("public" button) it said me it will be visible only for developers before it'S public for everyone (Oct 1st) if I remember correctly. Thanks though

Comment: That's probably talking about just the button, not our actual Timeline release.

Comment: What about users listed as 'Admins' of the app? I'm developing an app, and it won't let me be both the Admin and the Developer.

Comment: yea, admins / developers / testers should all be able to see it.